# Applying SentimentIntensityAnalyzer function on each row of the dataframe & providing the sentiment score

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have written a small program calling `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` function from `nltk.sentiment.vader` library in Python. I want to analyze comments mentioned in column c2 & provide sentiment score in the new adjacent column. There are 10,000 comments & my comments are in `remarks.txt` file. I have created `get_sentiment()` function but facing issues passing each row of the data frame as argument & calling it using for loop to provide sentiment score & store it in adjacent column.

I tried these codes:

```
df['add'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_sentiment(row))
```

Couldn't find the solution anywhere on the internet. Codes are as follows:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
remarks = pd.read_csv('/Users/ZKDN0YU/Desktop/comments/Comments.txt', 
sep='\t')
remarks.head(50)
df = pd.DataFrame(remarks)
print(df)
def get_sentiment(remarks):
 sentiment_score = sid.polarity_scores(row)
 positive_meter = round((sentiment_score['pos'] * 10), 2)
 negative_meter = round((sentiment_score['neg'] * 10), 2)
 return positive_meter, negative_meter

for index, row in df.iterrows():
 df['add'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_sentiment(row)) 
 print(row['c1'], row['c2'],"Positive",positive_meter,"Negative", 
 negative_meter)
```

Getting following error while running above codes:

```
File "<ipython-input-9-7223b4fb6bd7>", line 10, in get_sentiment
 sentiment_score = sid.polarity_scores(row)

NameError: ("name 'sid' is not defined", 'occurred at index c1')
```

Comment: It seems like you've forgotten to define `sid`, hence the error. `sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()` might help?

Comment: Got it... Error pertaining to sid has been resolved. working on other error. Thanks!

Comment: great! what errors have you got? I might be better to share sample data & expected output, so that anyone could run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['add'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_sentiment(row)) 
    print(row['c1'], row['c2'],"Positive",positive_meter,"Negative", 
    negative_meter)
```

with

```py
df['positive'] = df.c2.apply(get_sentiment, k='positive')
df['negative'] = df.c2.apply(get_sentiment, k='negative')

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
   print("Positive : {}, Negative : {}".format(row['positive'], row['negative']))
```

Here we apply the function to all values in the c2 column of the dataframe and return a series to the new column 'add' in the DataFrame.

The get_sentiment function also need to be updated with this solution:

```py
def get_sentiment(row, **kwargs):
 # Your previous code 
   return positive_meter if kwargs['k'] == 'positive' else negative_meter
```

Comment: I tried these above codes :-
df['add'] = df.c2.apply(get_sentiment) 
print(row['c1'], row['c2'],"Positive",positive_meter,"Negative", 
negative_meter) 

but getting this error 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5179, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Wondering if I am passing the right argument to get_sentiment() function.

Comment: I have updated my anwer. Was a bit too fast on the trigger for the previous one. Try if it works  (I have no possibility to try it myself at the moment.)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Håkan ! Getting this error after trying codes.

 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4028, in f
    return func(x, *args, **kwds)

TypeError: get_sentiment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'

Comment: Third time's the charm. I have updated the comment again - now tested.

Comment: Tested the codes...now getting this error.
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\sentiment\vader.py", line 284, in __init__
    text = str(text.encode('utf-8'))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: This is an exception in the nltk.sentiment.vader lib. I don't know if it will help but you can try to pass the argument as string by casting it, i.e. `sentiment_score = sid.polarity_scores(str(row))`

Comment: In case if i want to get the Positive, Negative & Neutral keywords as well from sentimentIntensityAnalyzer for each row of comments & print it in adjacent columns...How can i do that?